# No me muestra el alert()

Tags: javascript, html, alert

No me muestra el alert() del rol repetido cuando presiono en el boton registrar, pero en el ultimo registro si me muestra el alert(),que en este caso es Portero. No se a que se deba, solo me funciona con los primeroS registros...adjunto la parte del codigo js

```
const registrar=()=>{
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", nombre.value);
    let nom=ref("");
    dato.value.forEach((elem:any)=>{
        nom.value=elem.name
    })
    if(nombre.value==""){
        alert("El campo esta vacio..")
        return
    }else if(nombre.value==nom.value){
        alert("Rol repetido..")
        return
    }
```

Codigo html del boton Añadir

```
<v-row class="btn">
            <v-col class="btn_mas">
                <v-btn class="elevation-5 text-blue-grey-darken-4 bg-blue-grey-lighten-5 rounded-lg" @click="registrar()">Añadir</v-btn>
            </v-col>
            
        </v-row>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es esto

```
dato.value.forEach((elem:any)=>{
   nom.value=elem.name
})
```

Tienes un bucle que asigna en cada iteracón el valor del item del array, al finalizar el bucle te quedar con que `nom.value` es igual al último item.

Para buscar repetidos puedes usar [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) el cual te indicará si existe al menos un elemento que cumple la condición, ejemplo:

```
const registrar=()=>{
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", nombre.value);
    let nom=ref("");

    if(nombre.value==""){
        alert("El campo esta vacio..")
        return
    }else if(dato.value.some(a=> a.name === nombre.value )){
        alert("Rol repetido..")
        return
    }
```